# MySQL trigger change primary id before insert

Tags: mysql, triggers, database-trigger

My goal is to prevent two columns from being the same integer.

```
id, relative
1,4
2,4
3,4
4,4 (NO!)
5,4
```

I would like to make a trigger to skip one id (primary key) value if the relative is equal to the id before insert. Desired result:

```
id, relative
1,4
2,4
3,4
5,4 
6,4
```

Here is the part of the trigger I am trying to make work:

```
if new.relative=new.id then set new.id=new.id+1;
end if;
```

But it's not doing anything. How can I make this work?

Comment: This would be trivial to do in application code. Why in the database?

Comment: Because it's just a safeguard for any insert. Allows me to add that primary id later if needed just in case it is ever missing in the database in the first place.

Comment: Altering the behaviour of the `AUTO_INCREMENT` in this way is asking for trouble. You should probably just stub in empty records to pre-populate that ID if necessary. Your question isn't entirely clear, either. Are there two requirements here? A) That `id` and `relative` do not have identical values and B) that `id` skips any values already present in `relative`?

Comment: indeed and doing it in the application code like you suggested before @tadman is also asking for some trouble with possible race conditions if implemented wrong..

Comment: @RaymondNijland If the `id` and `relative` values are pre-populated then it can be done application side. If not, you're right, race conditions can exist.

Comment: Ok I understand. I will avoid changing the ID. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you implemented the trigger, bu this is the syntax

**Code**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER same_value 
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON table_name 
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (table_name.id = table_name.relative) 
BEGIN 
#whatever you want to implement 
END;
```

**Resources**

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_triggers.htm

Comment: PL/SQL is for Oracle, not MySQL.